# JavaScript string concatenation is slower than in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, performance, concatenation

I know, there are similar questions and answers, I'm asking just because of fact that amazed me.
I'm ruby developer and write ruby code every day, run ruby programs every day and I always considered it the **slowest** in the world.
Can't believe that Ruby has at least one faster operation, but here it is:

Ruby:

```
start = Time.now
s = ''
100000.times do |i|
  s << 's'.freeze
end
puts s.size
puts Time.now - start
```

2.5.0 version: 0.015s, 0.020ms without `freeze`

2.4.1 version: 0.013s

JS: (was executed via node.js)

```
var start = Date.now()
s = ''
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  s += 's'
}
console.log(s.length)
console.log((Date.now() - start) / 1000)
```

0.021s, with array joining it little bit slower

And bonus:

```
local time = require('socket').gettime
local start = time()
local s = {}
for i = 1, 100000 do
  s[i] = 's'
end
print(#table.concat(s))
print(time() - start)
```

0.003s, seven times faster than JS, it's ok, it's LuaJIT.

So, if you are building template engine or there are thousands ways to use strings, the language, that even getting slower with new versions, can be faster than JS, and this blows up my mind.

Does JavaScript have any tricks for concatenation?

(edit) I wrote ms first time, but meant seconds

Comment: Use an array and `join` it at the end? Or, in your particular case, say `'s'.repeat(100000)`? JS strings aren't mutable the way Ruby strings are, so concatenation involves copying.

Comment: Join is slower, and it is just simplification, not particular case, seriously?

Comment: You trust such benchmarks in *micro*second range?

Comment: Joining at the end is 3x faster in my tests with your code.

Comment: And you even include printing time in such tiny benchmarks... seriously?

Comment: Lua strings aren't mutable too, LuaJIT uses black magic on array-like structure instead. Anyway immutable nature of strings in scripting languages is sad, interpretator should provide some kind of crutch for this

Comment: Immutability is a good thing. Realize that that string in Ruby *can be modified by the caller after it's been passed*, leading to all kinds of stupid trickery that can only be prevented by either not keeping it, or defensively copying it every time. The second you do that, mutable strings lose a lot of their performance benefits.

Comment: @cHao in my chromium array really faster, not very much.
I've tested in node.js 9.4.0

Comment: @cHao If string concatenation in JS involves copying, wouldn't this be copying five billion characters in 0.000021 seconds? Hard to believe.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Looks unreliably, but time is stable no matter how many times tests were executed. If instead of 100000 I will place 1m or 10m - time will grow in tests respectively.
Why not to trust?
I many times read that no one can trust no benchmarks, microbenchmarks always lies, large code always will be wrote in different ways so it is incomparable. I think question about trust is personal.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Maybe there's some magic happening behind the scenes. But yes, *something* is certainly getting copied. The strings i'm concatenating are the same as before.

Comment: @cHao yes, my fault, I meant seconds, 0.021 second. My laptop is far from supercomputer.

Comment: Either way it's not all that relevant. If you care about the performance of repeating a string a hundred thousand times, have fun with Ruby. :)  If you care about the performance of nearly everything else, pick Node. (Or any other language, for that matter.) If you'd rather just get stuff done and realize the difference is negligible the vast majority of the time, use whatever you want.

Comment: Agree with you that perfomance of everything else in node is much higher, but still, concatenation is fundamental, it's present in all programs, for template engines it really can be executed thousands times per one rendering. This strange benchmark was born when I was thinking why template rendering in my app is the slowest part, slower than internet traffic, slower than database (complex) requests

Comment: How freaking complex are your templates? And what system are you using?

Comment: Well, it's Ruby on Rails, no one knows where it spends most of the time, so template engine is just assumption. There is layout, template and partials. All of them have many concatenations with I18n translations, layout contains concats of signed user variables, template too, and template can render partials many times. Honestly yes, they are freacking complex in some parts.